# Preseed with new packages

Tags: 14.04, preseed

I'm doing an unattended installation (preseeded) with Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to install additional packages during installation. 
I used:

```
d-i pkgsel/include openssh-server
```

In my preseed file, but this does not work. What will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly none of the proposed solutions worked for me on 14.04.
I solved it with a script that is run on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you used is incorrect. You need to specify what type the parameter is, like so:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string build-essential git openssh-server
```

However, for SSH, you can use the task instead. For example:

```
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop, openssh-server
```

Comment: I've tried both approaches and none of them works.

Comment: @kovica personally, both work for me, so look through the logs to see what's happening in your case.

Comment: Are you using 14.04 or 12.05?